# Can't log into Ubuntu One for Android

Tags: android

Just installed Ubuntu One into my SonyEricsson, I run Android 2.2 on that device.
The Problem is to log into Ubuntu One, I tried both WiFi and 3g-net.
But Ubuntu One only says that "Service Unavailable" I run Ubuntu 11.04 on both Laptop and Desktop and only problem I have there is syncronisation of bookmarks in Firefox. But thats another problem =)

Hope I can get Ubuntu One to work on cellphone

Comment: This also worked for me, but for step 3) I had to manually set the time wrong, then check automatic, and restart the phone before having success at step 4.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following:

1. device > Settings > Manage applications > Ubuntu One Files > Force close, Clear app data
2. device > Settings > Accounts & sync > remove the Ubuntu account
3. device > Settings > Date & time > Automatic -- checked
4. relaunch Ubuntu One Files and try again :)

If you have further issues, please contacts us using this form :)
https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/

Comment: This worked for me and my T-Mobile G2.