# ubuntu one login problem from android

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

My ubuntu one account get login correctly by firefox and nautilus.

My account has a 16 char password, with alphanumeric AND special chars.

It happens that downloading the ubuntu app in my   MTK6573 HD7 aHD7300 Android phone, I cannot login with the usual password.

Is there a problem in the Android app, not allowing special chars ?

Comment: Is the app going to connect via GPRS/3G or also with wifi ?

Comment: I also use special characters in my U1 password, and I have no problems with the Android app.

Answer (score 2):

Found a similar case in Askubuntu.
The problem seems solved removing ubuntuone app application data in the phone and restarting the app.

follow the link to:

[Can't log into Ubuntu One for Android](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63774/cant-log-into-ubuntu-one-for-android)

This solution solved my case.